# Fluent Nhibernate join without Id

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have tables

Person (id, Name)
and PersonAddInfo(PersonId,SpecialStatus)

i have classes

```
public class Person 
{
public virtual int Id {get;set;}
public virtual string Name {get;set;}
public virtual PersonAddInfo Info {get;set;}//What i want to have
}

and

public class PersonAddInfo
{
public virtual int PersonId {get;set;}
public virtual string SpecialStatus {get;set;}
}
```

Now i want my Person to have new field

```
public virtual PersonAddInfo Info {get;set;}
```

Or some of PersonAddInfo's fields

How can i map\override Person class to get such possibility

Answer (score 0):

```
        mapping.Join("PersonAddInfo ", m =>
        {
            m.Optional();
            m.KeyColumn("PersonId");
            m.Map(x => x.SpecialStatus );
        });
```

Here we go